# Java Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding"); equivalent in C#? I can't encrypt message in .net framework application

Tags: java, c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

My friend has simply method in Java:

```
 public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] msg, PrivateKey key) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(msg);
    }
```

I need to encrypt message the same way in C#. I tried to use

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
provider.FromXmlString(privkey);
byte[] encryptedEverything = provider.Encrypt(message, false/*tried every options of this constructor*/);
```

but i have a `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Bad Length.'`. 
When i splited my `byte[256]` message to two `byte[128]` messages, sign, and then merge them i finally had a byte[512] message. I know why, but i had to try.

How to sign this message with c# .net Framework? Is there any equivalent for Java Cipher? .net looks to be very careful with cryptography, i dont know why.

Comment: I had same issue years ago.  I finally tried every combination of parameters.  I put each option in a separate for loop and then added an exception handle so when I got an exception the loops would continue.   Tried something like 128 combinations and found the compatible one.  I had an encrypted message that was output by java.  It was easier to first to get decryption to work.

Comment: @jdweng wow, so there is not one answer to my question? Can you find this class? or is it impassible? :(

Answer (score 1):

Your friend has a simply *insecure* method to perform encryption. You should never use "NoPadding" as that would be using "textbook" or "raw" RSA. To show what attacks are possible if you do can be found [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20085/1172) (note the person asking the question for this specific purpose). `NoPadding` does indeed not be available in the Microsoft classes - I presume using `null` doesn't work.

Furthermore, to encrypt larger messages you should be using *hybrid encryption* where a randomly generated AES key is wrapped (/encrypted) using the public RSA key, and the message specific AES key is then used to encrypt the data. That way you can encrypt any size of message, and you just get a one time overhead of - in your case - 128 bytes for a 1024 bit RSA key (both regarding performance *and* size of encrypted message).

You'd want to use a larger key size than 1024 bits though, I'd at least double the key size. I'd also consider one of the OAEP schemes instead. There are attacks possible on PKCS#1 padding, so those are arguably less secure than the newer OAEP schemes.

Comment: Have you any sample how to use hybrid encryption in this case?

Comment: [This one](https://riptutorial.com/java/example/7290/an-example-using-a-hybrid-cryptosystem-consisting-of-oaep-and-gcm) looks rather OK, although using GCM with public key crypto is a bit dangerous; you'd want to *sign* the data as an adversary can also encrypt using the public key, so the authentication tag doesn't protect against all scenarios... I'd rather use CTR and add a signature, but both CTR and GCM seem to be missing in action in C#, and CBC is vulnerable against padding oracle attacks.

Comment: Hmm. MS has a good choice here. In general, I think no padding was available since the programmer will handle it. But in general, totally eliminating seems a good action.

Comment: @kelalaka Well, there are secure schemes such as RSA-KEM that do not use any padding, and since exposing the private key operation isn't thought to make the private key at risk, it does make the API much less flexible. RSA without padding is insecure, but the user could have their own secure scheme in mind. I would have added `None` as option in a lower-end, general purpose API... I'm not sure if `null` would work, but I suppose not. I've actually removed that "for good purpose" from my answer.

Comment: That is a reason to include `NoPadding`, in my opinion, too. However, what we see here, in general, people use it without reading it. Maybe, there should be a code-time, compile-time, or run-time warnings if `NoPadding` is used that can be suppressed like in Java annotations.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can configure your favorite code checker to do so, and I am pretty sure that security-targeting tools already do this. It is another question if the Java *compiler* needs to check the contents of a string (or parameter value / choice of enum). But honestly, these kind of decisions should be put in a protocol description and then reviewed. If you let the developer make the choice himself then you're already too late (the dev. can take the role of designer and post the protocol on github for review, in case of lone wolf).

Comment: hmm no matter how insecure will be this app, if i want to be hacked, why somebody want to disallow me to do that? i just want to make a simply app working on localhost to make simply requests to other (an old app) to rewrite this api. it still don't need even internet connection in that first app.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ad. your comment from 12hours ago, i mean C# hybrid encryption

Comment: You can use Bouncy Castle to perform raw modular exponentiation (or rather raw CRT based calculations for private key operations, but yeah). I think it will always now left-pad zero bytes where required to get a result that has the same size in octets as the modulus, but I'd rather make sure of that. If it is not in the official API then you need a library or do it yourself, but the latter is not recommended for crypto as it invariably leads to e.g. timing attacks. But as you are already hellbound to shoot yourself in the foot...

Answer (score -1):

These days it's discouraged to use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` as it only works on Windows. What I usually do is have my public keys and private keys in **PEM format**, and load it using a [helper library](https://nuget.org/packages/Ultz.Extensions.PrivacyEnhancedMail) I wrote a while back.

Here's a sample that will load a PEM private key and encrypt some data using PKCS #1:

```
var privateKeyString = File.ReadAllText(privateKeyPath);
var rsa = PemExt.DecodeRsaPrivateKey(PemExt.GetBytesFromPem(privateKeyString, "RSA PRIVATE KEY"));
var encryptedEverything = rsa.Encrypt(message, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
```

If you also have the public key, you can load both using the `Pem.GetCertificateAndKey` method which is far less complex.

```
var privateKeyString = File.ReadAllText(privateKeyPath);
var publicKeyString = File.ReadAllText(publicKeyPath);
var (cert, rsa) = Pem.GetCertificateAndKey(publicKeyString, privateKeyString);
var encryptedEverything = rsa.Encrypt(message, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
```

Comment: hmm i have ```System.ArgumentNullException: 'Buffer cannot be null.
Parameter name: buffer'```

Comment: You may want to look at key sizes : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.keysizes?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Although this is all good advice, it doesn't solve the issue in the question.